# status bar issue while orientation changes in ios while playing video

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue when play youtube video on iOS   That is, after play vieo at full screen mode at landscape (my app just supports portrait mode), or if user press Done during playing video, the status bar will not rotate.

Approx same link is : [iOS status bar orientation after play video fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426083/ios-status-bar-orientation-after-play-video-fullscreen)

Comment: there is no code just issue when i play a video status bar fixed. Here is a same link of issue what i am facing .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426083/ios-status-bar-orientation-after-play-video-fullscreen

Comment: you mean your orientation is not changing according  when you are changing device  oreintation

Comment: no thats working fine but not working in case of video play full screen. That stuck at like image.

Comment: Call  `[super viewWillAppear]`  in `viewWillAppear` at first line.

Comment: I dont think this works